# Unity- should moving object in 'X' Axis be in Update or fixedUpdate.?

Tags: unity-game-engine

i know physics should be in fixedupdate. but what about moving the object in 'X' Axis forever, does it also count as physics movement?

```
    void Update () {
    Vector3 temp = transform.position;
    temp.x += speed * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.position = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting it in Update should be fine

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: hey, but isn't its a physics ??

Comment: No,not really. This code moves the GameObject each frame on its own with no outside influence, so it's generally okay to put it in Update. This would be different if it contained actual physics calculations, if it did then it's generally recommended to put physics calculations in FixedUpdate. But as it is, the function doesn't need changing :)